# Why isn't my view loading?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, ibaction

I'm following a tutorial (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QnSUl5_ccp0) - yet I'm running into a problem. I have this code, yet in the simulator it's not opening the new view when I tap the button. As far as I know, it's supposed to load the next view, passing over the correct information regarding the in app purchase details.

```
 - (IBAction)PurchaseItem:(id)sender {

    _purchaseController = [[PurchasedViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    _purchaseController.productID = @"myapp.testiapapp";
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:_purchaseController];
    [self presentViewController:_purchaseController animated:YES completion:NULL];
    [_purchaseController getProductID:self];

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know if your method is being called at all?

Comment: I'm an amateur when it comes to iOS Development - but I'm not sure. Where would I find that? When I click the button, nothing happens.

Comment: set a breakpoint at the first line and see if it breaks there. (If you have line number showing, click the line number to add a breakpoint)

Comment: @CrispyG Sorry to be the bearer of bad news but programming is all about trial, error and debugging. No one can teach and debug the code for you unless you do it yourself. keep testing and debugging your app till you figure out what the problem is. Go through tons of tutorials not just the first one that comes up on google.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Sam, I've had to do that for many other apps before. In fact, I usually try and find a tutorial that explains things well, then adapt everything and start from new when I want to turn it into an app.  For a breakpoint, putting it on the first line of the code means the simulator exists and shows the breakpoint when the button is tapped.

Comment: I've tried moving a few things round and re-adding the button link, and it just brings up a black screen this time when tapping the button.

Comment: Here is a tutorial that does a complete walk-through. I used it when I was first starting to do in-app purchases within my app. Some of the code maybe old and out-dated http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/

Comment: Here is apple official documentation with code examples - https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Products.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. Effectively I'm trying to create an IAP that allows you to unlock a button to take you to a different view.